# How to configure Apache Hadoop Vaidya

Tags: apache, hadoop

As I'm looking for tuning my hadoop map-reduce jobs to get better performance with optimal resource utilization, but I'm unable to start Can any one tell me how to configure Apache Hadoop Vaidya. I was following apache blog for [Hadoop Vaidya](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/vaidya.html), it has described very well how to use it. 
In some blog i found a path

> $HADOOP_HOME/contrib/vaidya/bin/

which is not present in my machine so I'm assuming that i have to **install/configure** Apache Hadoop Vaidya.

Any help will be appreciated!!